# Orthonormal columns of block matrix yield certain property?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, block-matrices

Let $W_1,W_2,W_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ be such that

$$\eqalign{
 \Big[\matrix{W_1^T&W_2^T&W_3^T}\Big]\cdot\left[\matrix{W_1\\W_2\\W_3}\right]\cdot = I
}$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. I'm a bit lost here but I expect then that the following holds for  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$

$$\eqalign{
 \Big[\matrix{A^TW_1^T&A^TW_2^T&A^TW_3^T}\Big]\cdot\left[\matrix{W_1A\\W_2A\\W_3A}\right] = A
}$$

Is that the case?

Comment: @user1551 I've edited my question

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$$
\pmatrix{A^TW_1^T&A^TW_2^T&A^TW_3^T}\pmatrix{W_1A\\ W_2A\\ W_3A}
=A^T\pmatrix{W_1^T&W_2^T&W_3^T}\pmatrix{W_1\\ W_2\\ W_3}A
=A^TA.
$$
Whether $A^TA$ is equal to $A$ depends on the exact value of $A$ itself.